# How to get Hard Disk number from drive letter using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

How to get Hard Disk number from drive letter using VBScript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By "hard disk number", do you mean the serial number or something else?

Comment: No, I don't mean the serial number. I mean the nuber (designation) that is determined by the bios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remou is right about WMI, just have to make it a little bit more messy. Wouldn't be at all surprised if there's an easier/better way of doing this, but this script should at least give you a good starting point for doing what you need.

```
Dim query 
Dim objWMI 
Dim diskDrives 
Dim diskDrive 
Dim partitions 
Dim partition ' will contain the drive & partition numbers
Dim logicalDisks 
Dim logicalDisk ' will contain the drive letter

Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set diskDrives = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive") ' First get out the physical drives
For Each diskDrive In diskDrives 
    query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + diskDrive.DeviceID + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition" ' link the physical drives to the partitions
    Set partitions = objWMI.ExecQuery(query) 
    For Each partition In partitions 
        query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + partition.DeviceID + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"  ' link the partitions to the logical disks 
        Set logicalDisks = objWMI.ExecQuery (query) 
        For Each logicalDisk In logicalDisks      
            Wscript.Echo logicalDisk.DeviceID & " - " & partition.Caption
        Next
    Next 
Next
```

This will enumerate all drive letters and give you the results as for example: `C: - Disk #2, Partion #0`

Answer (score 2):

How about WMI?

```
strComputer = "." 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
   s = s & "SerialNumber: " & objItem.SerialNumber & vbcrlf 
   s = s & "Model: " & objItem.Model
Next

MsgBox s
```

Comment: This script obtains the serial number of the hard disk. I need to obtain the number that is determined by the BIOS. You can see this number in Disk Managment Menu.

Comment: Oops, I thought that was what you said, re-reading, I see it is not.

Comment: WMI returns a lot of information (http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_disks_physical.htm)you can also get the code creator http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wmigen.php.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the exact answer but in case some need it in C# use this function that I just created

```
    private string GetDiskIndex(string driveLetter)
    {
        driveLetter = driveLetter.TrimEnd('\\');

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
        var drives = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")).Get();
        foreach(var drive in drives)
        {

            var partitions = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + drive["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition")).Get();
            foreach(var partition in partitions)
            {
                var logicalDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + partition["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")).Get();
                foreach (var logicalDisk in logicalDisks)
                {
                    if (logicalDisk["DeviceId"].ToString() == driveLetter) return partition["DiskIndex"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:vbscript] not [tag:c#], please post this in the appropriate topic question.